# Default method for Ruby class

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to specify a class method such that when the object is used as if it were a function, that method is called? Something like this:

```
class MyClass

  def some_magic_method(*args)
    # stuff happens
  end

end

# create object
myob = MyClass.new

# implicitly call some_magic_method
myob 'x'
```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: `some_magic_method` is written as an instance method, not a class method. `myob 'x'` raises an "undefined method 'myob'" exception. If you mean `myob.x` you could use [BasicObject#method_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing), but that is an instance method.

Comment: This makes no sense. There is absolutely no relationship between the message `myob` and the variable `myob`. How do you expect `myob` to know about the message?

Comment: @JörgWMittag maybe the question looks strange for a Ruby programmer but the concept is perfectly valid and supported by other languages (C++ and PHP are the ones I know). I have to admit, however, that neither C++ nor PHP are as elegant as Ruby regarding the OOP.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @CarySwoveland in the comments you can use `method_missing`. A basic example is as follows:

```
class MyClass

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if method_name.match?(/[xyz]/)
      send(:magic_method, args.first) 
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def magic_method(a)
    a = 'none' if a.nil?
    "xyz-magic method; argument(s): #{a}"
  end

end

myob = MyClass.new
myob.x    #=> "xyz-magic method; argument(s): none"
myob.x(1) #=> "xyz-magic method; argument(s): 1"

myob.y    #=> "xyz-magic method; argument(s): none"
myob.z    #=> "xyz-magic method; argument(s): none"
```

This captures all methods named x, y or z. Our `else` branch sends all other undefined methods to the original `method_missing`:

```
myob.v    #=> test.rb:7:in `method_missing': undefined method `v' for
              #<MyClass:0x000000021914f8> (NoMethodError)
              #from test.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

What methods you capture is up to you and is determined by the regex `/[xyz]/` in this case.

---

*Key methods:* [`BasicObject#method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing), [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send). For further info check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400344/how-to-use-rubys-metaprogramming-to-reduce-method-count/43406099#43406099), read *Eloquent Ruby* by Russ Olsen (from which this answer references)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a command class and make use of a ruby shortcut

```
class MyClass
  def self.call(text)
    puts text
  end
end

MyClass.('x')
```

Here `MyClass.()` defaults to the `call` class method.

Answer (score 0):

You meant to invoke some class' `instance method` when the object is invoked as a function. This is already supported: instance method `call` gets called when you "invoke" an object via the functional invocation method `()` (for more details, see here [How do I reference a function in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294485/how-do-i-reference-a-function-in-ruby/4294660#4294660)).

```
class C
  def call(x)
    puts "Called with #{x}"
  end
end

obj = C.new
obj.(88) # Called with 88 => nil
obj (88) # NoMethodError: undefined method `obj' for main:Object
```

If you do want the latter syntax, a horrible trick is the following one (but works only at the top-level, unless you carry along the bindings):

```
module Kernel
  def method_missing(name,*args)
    obj = begin
      TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_get(name)
    rescue
      nil
    end
    return super if obj.nil? 
    obj.send :call, *args
  end
end

obj = C.new

obj 88 # Called with OK => nil
```

This example also wants to communicate that you should always keep in mind 
**who** is the **receiver** of your method calls, and what syntaxes are available for calling methods (especially when you leave out dots and parentheses).

```
class D
  def obj; C.new end
  def f
    #(obj) 88 # BAD 
    (obj).(88) 
    #obj() 88 # BAD 
    obj().(88) 
  end
end
```

The point is that you do not actually have functions, but methods that get called on objects. If you omit the receiver of a method call, the receiver defaults to `self`, the current object. But in your example, `myob` does not appear as an explicit receiver (since there is not following dot as in `myob.`), hence the current object is looked for a method `myob`.